# Different behavior of incomplete character set handling between Mac and Linux for R

Tags: r, macos, fonts, ggplot2, cairo

I am using a trial font to create some figures in R using ggplot2. (In case anyone is interested, I am using this https://www.grillitype.com/typefaces/gt-walsheim)
Trial version of this font only provides a limited set of characters, which means that symbols like "=" are not included in the trial version. So I am generating graphs under both Linux and Mac using ggplot2 and cairo_pdf. In Linux, the missing characters in the font I am using are automatically substituted with a fallback typeface such as Helvetica, but this is not happening in Mac OS. I have searched the netweb for this question, but so far have no answer as to why this is happening.
In Mac OS El Capitan, the generated title looks like this:
[image: Macversion], which  does not have the character "=" automatically substituted. In Linux however, the title looks fine:[image], with the missing character "=" automatically substituted with another typeface. 
So my question is, how do I make this happen in Mac OS El Capitan as well??? Thanks a bunch!!

Comment: Use a different font.

Answer (score 0):

In the 90's computer fonts were expensive objects, often released under restrictive licenses. Windows and OS/X got around by commissioning a restricted font set, and using it everywhere (arial + times new roman + courier for windows, etc).

Linux systems had no such possibility, their distribution model required specific licensing conditions most font foundries were not agreable with, so they had to make to with the few limited fonts that were available.

Improvements in font creation tools lowered font costs drastically, and sustained advocacy efforts convinced font foundries it would not be the end of the world to release some fonts under less restrictive terms (making the Open font Library, and Google font directory possible). So nowadays Linux systems also ship with extensive font collections.

Also Linux systems always supported every possible language in one release, so they had to work out how to deal with font conflicts. Apple and Microsoft mostly worked around the problem by releasing different OS versions for different regions, with different non-conflicting font sets.

As a result the Linux font stack integrates extensive support to workaround font problems (autohinting, substitution, etc). You won't find the same level of support on OS/X or windows. Apple and Microsoft always considered the solution to incomplete fonts was to pay for more extensive versions.